# How to understand 節がある?

Tags: idioms

According to weblio, 節｛ふし｝がある is defined as follow:

> 着眼点としてある。そのようにも思われる。「思い当たるふしがある」や、「県警は当初、事件を隠蔽しようとしていたふしがある」などのように用いられる。
>
> "Interesting" point. Considered to be like this. Used like 「思い当たるふしがある」 and 「県警は当初、事件を隠蔽しようとしていたふしがある」.

But I can't grasp what it would mean. 思い当たるふしがある is like "if someone mentions it that appears to be evident" and 「県警は当初、事件を隠蔽しようとしていたふしがある」 would maybe mean "At first, the police tried to keep the case secret". But I fail to get the nuances.

I have found a lot of examples [here](http://yourei.jp/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B) but I can't still make anything of it.

In particular,

> 頭と胴体と、強い方が相手を制するのではないかと思われるふしがある。

The combination 思われるふしがある makes little sense to me.

Could someone clarify a bit what it means? or how can it be reformulated?

Comment: I don't fully grasp it either looking at the definition, but one trick that at least puts me in the vicinity is 同義語 (http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B) which gives me a pretty good idea of what one could substitute for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this 節 is more or less interchangeable with [ところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23739/5010), and it vaguely refers to "something that catches one's eyes" or "something that reminds someone of something". I feel it tends to refer to something negative or suspicious.

Anyway, this phrase is idiomatic, and safe translations would simply be "It appears to me that ～", "It reminded me of ～". I feel 言われてみると ("now that you've mentioned") is not always important, and your last example can be translated simply as "It seems that the stronger one will win."

Answer (score 0):

思い当たる: come to mind

> ふし【節】 ３ 心のとまるところ。…と思われる点。
>   http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/192283/meaning/m1u/
>   sign, clue, evidence, irregularity, anomaly, indication, trace, vestige, mark, concern.

思い当たるふしがある
Some clues come to mind.

県警は当初、事件を隠蔽しようとしていたふしがある
There are evidences that the police at first tried to keep the case secret.

思われるふしがある 
There are some evidences that makes one think so.

Comment: 思い当たる節がある：「言われてみると、該当すると思われる点があることに気づく、といった意味の表現。『ふし』（節）はこの場合、着目するべき箇所といった意味。」Weblioから。「Some clues come to mind.」という表現は「言われてみると」という部分を無視しているんではありませんか。この表現を忠実的に説明するのはし難いとは認めますが、

Comment: I am not Japanese, you have to speak English with me.
According to the dictionary 節(fushi) means  心のとまるところ。
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/192283/meaning/m1u/
So 節 is anything that draws your attention. Anything that is out of normal, out of ordinary.
Depending on  the context this can be translated as "clue"
clue: anything that serves to guide or direct in the solution of a problem, mystery, etc. 
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/clue?s=t
There is nothing in the dictionary about 「言われてみると」

Comment: I missed the "こころがとまるところ" definition thanks for pointing it out. (For the 言われてみると part, I pasted verbatim the definition of 思い当たる節がある from weblio). (I am more looking for intuition behind the meaning than proper translation). The こころがとまるところ really answered my question so you might include it in your answer.

Comment: @永劫回帰: I believe the definition `心のとまるところ。…と思われる点` is the answer to your question although it isn't explained well in this answer. Basically certain points or something lingering in your heart that you can feel is the 節.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual definition of weblio: `何かが起こる前触れを感じ取ること`

which after some thinking about, I would understand as `to see signs of`

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Please take a look at this image. 節 should be derived from tree burl....

Copyright: https://www.umee-seizaisho.com/special10.html