# I could use help with the finer nuances of 節、柄、and 様。

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

Why is it 節 that goes in __ in the following, not 様 or 柄？
部長は、毎日残業するのを当たり前だと思っている__がある。
This is a question in a textbook I'm using to prep for NI JLPT, and 節 is given as the answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might find this question helpful: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41058

Answer (score 2):

According to the dictionary:

ふし【節】心のとまるところ。…と思われる点。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/192283/meaning/m1u/節/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/192283/meaning/m1u/%E7%AF%80/)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/節/#je-65902](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%AF%80/#je-65902)

Examples:
疑{うたが}わしい節{ふし}が二、三ある。
There are 2 or 3 suspicious items.

彼{かれ}の説{せつ}にはどうかと思{おも}われる節{ふし}が二，三ある。
There are a few disputable points in his theory.

ふし is some characteristic, irregularity, something weird  that may catch your attention.

So the manager (部長) thinks it is normal to work extra hours every day, but the writer thinks it is weird.

Comment: It seems that this is a pattern 節が(＃)ある where a counting or approximation could be used in place of # but is not necessary, whenever referring to something that is irregular to the speaker.