Trying to understand 節がある
彼さんは己を猛獣と思う節があるからこそ、檻に突ッ込まれる自覚があったんだ。
"節がある" is a word I've seen a bit in reading more advanced material, however I still struggle to actually understand what it means.
In this sentence, the character is reflecting the fact he got framed by by 彼さん
As far I can see, the sentence could be read as because he thinks of me as as beast he was reading to throw me into a cage. Essentially, "kare" thinks of him as dispensable.
What I struggle is "節がある" here. Some googling suggest it can be fundamentally change with 気がする?

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41058

節がある is a set phrase, but you can understand 節 used like this is a noun meaning "something that clicks in your mind" or "something that reminds you of something". When asked "Are you a beast?", an ordinary person would say no without any hesitation. While this person (彼さん) also doesn't explicitly think he is a beast, he feels something nagging in his mind when asked like that.
Possible translations would be:

彼さんは己を猛獣と思う節があった。

Something in him resonated with the idea that he might be a beast.
Deep down, there were hints that he regarded himself as a beast.



Than kyou. For context though.   I believe the main character is explaining the reasoning he got betrayed so 彼 should be his enemy and 己 himself.
