# What is 所があるじゃない in this context？

Tags: grammar

In this sentence (from a manga), what does 所があるじゃない stand for? I don't seem to understand the grammar behind it.

> それにしても鬼灯尹も結構可愛い所があるじゃないか。

(I mean, I know about 所が meaning however, 所がある meaning 'there is', じゃない as ではありません, but that seems to be something else here.)

Answer (score 3):

According to JMDict, one of the meanings of 所 is as follows:

- point
- aspect
- side
- fact

Therefore, in this sentence, "可愛い所" means something like "cute side".

One could translate just that part of the sentence as follows:

> 可愛い所があるじゃないか
>
> isn't there a cute side?

Specifically, the speaker is saying that there is a cute side to 鬼灯尹.

Related question/potential duplicate:

- [Meaning of ところ in アメリカのいいところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/meaning-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d-in-%e3%82%a2%e3%83%a1%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ab%e3%81%ae%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 「鬼灯」is a name, it's a way of saying he has many cute things to him/her.

> あるじゃない

Ending with じゃない in question form is like saying "isn't it?".

いいじゃない！ That's good isn't it?

Note: the negative would be よくない！

Also, よくないんじゃない！ That's bad isn't it? or "That's not good, is it?".

可愛い所 already answered by another comment, but you can use 所 to talk about "aspects" of something or someone.

優しいところが好きです。<- I like how (you/he/she) is nice.