# Trying to figure out how どんなとこ works

Tags: meaning, casual

> 他にどんなとこがよかったの？

The context is in S1E9 of Aggrestsuko in which Retsuko is asked about her new love. The official translation is "What else do you like about him?" but I am not sure how that is pulled from above. こと(ろ) causing the confusion.

Comment: とこ is short for ところ. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/meaning-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D-in-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D