# Japanese word for "side"

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word that means "side" like the one in "good side" or "cute side" 
I've searched and so far I found 面 so will it be 可愛い面? But the translation is face but I'm specifically looking for the word that means "side" or a word that is loosely like that.

Comment: Related?? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23738/9831

Comment: Consider what you're asking.  "Side" in English has **many** different meanings.  Which specific sense are you trying to translate?  You _could_ say that someone has a 「可愛い脇」, which is one completely correct way to translate _"cute side"_, for a specific sense of "side" -- but you'd get some very strange looks if you said that.  To translate better, you need to understand more deeply what you're asking about the English source that you're trying to translate into Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is ところ. Although the most common meaning is 'place', it is also used to describe aspects or points about something or someone. For example:

> 彼のいいところ His good side (lit. the good aspects of him).
>
> 彼女の可愛いところ Her cute side (lit. the cute aspects of her).
>
> 日本語のわかりやすいところ Easy parts of Japanese (lit. the easy aspects of Japanese).